# What is the purpose of {} in the returning type of a function?

Tags: scala

In the following function declaration:

```
def f(x: Int): Int {} = x + 1
```

what is the purpose of `{}`?

The result of the method invocation is the same with or without the curly braces.

Comment: Where/how did you find this?

Comment: I found it in the shapeless library https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/package.scala (search for def everything(f: Poly): )

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's just an empty refinement.
In Scala any type can have a refinement, that constrains the definitions of members (e.g., types, vals, defs) of the original type.

For example:

```
trait Base { type T }

type BaseInt = Base { type T = Int }
```

Those members don't have to be defined in any base type, the refined type can itself define new members.
And there are no restrictions on the type being refined, it is allowed to refine `AnyVal` or any of its subtypes. 
So the following code  is perfectly legal:

```
type A = Int { type C = Boolean; val a: String }
```

According to the [Scala specification](http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/03-types.html#compound-types):

> If no refinement is given, the empty refinement is implicitly added,
>   i.e. `T1 with … with Tn` is a shorthand for `T1 with … with Tn {}`.

So in your code `Int {}` is the same as `Int`.

---

Also, according to the specification, two types are considered equal if their refinements match exactly. So the following code results in a compile-time error:

```
scala> type A = Int { type C = Boolean; val a: String }
defined type alias A

scala> val a: A = 10 
<console>:12: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(10)
 required: A
    (which expands to)  Int{type C = Boolean; val a: String}
       val a: A = 10
                  ^
```

But as those refinements don't exist at runtime due to erasure, all casts are perfectly legal, if you don't use the members from refinements:

```
scala> val a: A = 10.asInstanceOf[A] 
a: A = 10
```

This feature can be used to implement [tagged types](http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/Tagged+type.html), that are the same and represented by some primitive type at runtime, but can be distinguished at compile time.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: @Octavian R. I have to ask one thing, pardon my tone. I was always wondering what makes people not accept perfectly good answers that completely addressed the given question? Do you simply forget, or you don't know for such a feature, or you want to triple-check it before accepting, or what?

Comment: @slouc if you take a look on my profile, you will see that this is my first question on stackoverflow and I didn't know that I have the option to mark a response as accepted. Now, thanks to you I saw it :). Besides, above your message, you can find my "thank you" message to Kolmar for the answer. So, you can consider that message as an acceptance for the answer.